# Prove that this specific sequence converges

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have to prove that this sequence converges. I have already shown that it is increasing, all thats left is to show it is upper bounded. However, I have no idea where to start. [image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Take the logarithm. Use a bound for $\log (1+x)$.